# On the construction of a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ by repeated subdivision

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

**Main Theme of the Question(s):** *Fractal Geometry* by Kenneth Falconer describes the following method to construct a mass distribution $\mu$ (and later, a measure on $\mathbb R^n$) on a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The author also says that we only concern ourselves with Borel sets. I need help understanding (i) the process of construction of this mass-distribution/measure, and (ii) the proof of a proposition that follows this discussion.

---

Slightly paraphrased from the book:

> The following method is often used to construct a mass distribution on a subset of $ℝ^n$. It involves repeated subdivision of a mass between parts of a bounded Borel set $E$. Let $\mathcal{E}_0$ consist of the single set $E$. For $k = 1, 2, . . . $, we let $\mathcal{E}_k$ be a collection of disjoint Borel subsets of $E$ such that each set $U$ in $\mathcal{E}_k$ is contained in one of the sets of $\mathcal{E}_{k−1}$ and contains a finite number of the sets in $\mathcal{E}_{k+1}$. We assume that the maximum diameter of the sets in $\mathcal{E}_k$ tends to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. We define a mass distribution on $E$ by repeated subdivision. We let $\mu(E) \in (0,\infty)$. In general, we assign masses so that $$\sum_i\mu(U_i) = \mu(U)$$ for each set $U$ of $\mathcal{E}_k$, where $\{U_i\}$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal{E}_{k+1}$ contained in $U$. For each $k$, let $E_k = \bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{E}_k} A$, and we define $\mu(A) = 0$ for all $A$ with $A\cap E_k = \varnothing$.
> [image]

Now the author states a proposition, which enables us to determine $\mu(A)$ for any *Borel* set $A$.

> *Proposition $1.7.$* Let $$ be defined on a collection of sets $\mathcal E$ as above. Then the definition of $$ may be extended to all subsets of $ℝ^n$ so that $$ *becomes a measure.* The value of
> $(A)$ is uniquely determined if $A$ is a Borel set. The support of $$ is contained in $E_∞ = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \overline{E_k}$.
> *Note on Proof.* If $A \subset \mathbb R^n$, let $$\mu(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): A \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$$
> It is not difficult to see that if $A\in\mathcal E$, then $\mu(A)$ above reduces to the mass $(A)$ specified in the construction. The complete proof that $$ satisfies all the conditions of a measure
> and that its values on the sets of $\mathcal E$ determine its values on the Borel sets is quite
> involved, and need not concern us here. As $(ℝ^n\setminus E_k) = 0$, we have $(A) = 0$ if $A$
> is an open set that does not intersect $E_k$ for some $k$, so the support of $$ is in $E_k$ for all $k$.

---

I have six questions:

1. In the proposition above, why is $\mu(A)$ defined the way it is (to extend $\mu$ to sets other than those in $\mathcal E$)?
2. How do I show that $\mu$ as defined above is in fact a measure on $\mathbb R^n$? The author says the proof is involved, but I want to see it. I need to prove three things:
   (a) $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$,
   (b) $A \subset B \implies \mu(A) \le \mu(B)$, 
   (c) $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$ with equality if $A_i$'s are disjoint Borel sets.

Here's what I've tried:
(a)$$\begin{align}
\mu(\varnothing) &= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): \varnothing \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}\\
&= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}
\end{align}$$
Why should $\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$ be $0$? I'm not sure if $\varnothing\in\mathcal E$.
(b) Suppose $A\subset B$. Then, $A\cap E_\infty \subset B\cap E_\infty$. We have $$\mu(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): A \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$$ and $$\mu(B) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): B \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$$ and from what I understand - $A\cap E_\infty \subset B\cap E_\infty$ directly implies $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$. This is due to the fact that any cover $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i$ of $B\cap E_\infty$ is also a cover of $A\cap E_\infty$, but the converse is not true in general. Since $A\cap E_\infty$ can possibly have *more covers* of the form $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i$ for $U_i\in\mathcal E$, the infimum of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i)$ over covers of $A\cap E_\infty$ is in general $\le$ the infimum of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i)$ over covers of $B\cap E_\infty$. Does this make sense?
(c)We have $$\mu(A_i) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): A_i \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$$ and $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(U_i): \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \cap E_\infty \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i \text{ and } U_i \in \mathcal{E}\right\}$$
Clearly, $A_i \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, and from the previous part, i.e. (b), we have $\mu(A_i) \le \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)$. I'm not sure how this helps, and I'm unable to proceed further.

3. Why does $E_∞ = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \overline{E_k}$ contain $\operatorname{spt}\mu$?

$\color{blue}{\text{Answered.}}$ As $\mu(\mathbb R^n \setminus E_k) = 0$, by monotonicity, we have $\mu(\Bbb R^n\setminus \overline{E_k}) = 0$. By the definition of support, $\operatorname{spt}\mu \subset \overline{E_k}$ for all $k$. So, $\operatorname{spt}\mu \subset E_\infty = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \overline{E_k}$.

4. If $A\in\mathcal E$, how does $\mu(A)$ (given by the wild expression in the proposition) reduce to the construction of $\mu(A)$ (i.e. the mass distribution earlier)?
5. How do we know that the value of $\mu$ on sets of $\mathcal E$ determines $\mu$ uniquely on all Borel sets?
6. What is the point of all this? What have we achieved? I need help understanding the bigger picture!

Thanks a lot for reading, and for your help (in advance)!

---

**References:**
Kenneth Falconer. *Fractal Geometry.*

Comment: What is $\mathcal{E}$? I only see $\mathcal{E}_k$ defined.

Comment: I think it's the union of all $\mathcal{E}_k$. Check the first line of Proposition 1.7, it says, "collection of sets $\mathcal E$ as above". If I'm not wrong, that's what it means. Looks like the author wasn't so explicit about this either. @lc2r43

Comment: Your argument for (b) is good. For (a) the empty cover covers $\emptyset$ which gives the empty sum i.e. $0$ so that $\mu(\emptyset)\leq 0$ (and of course $\geq 0$). I don't have a good argument for $E_\infty$ but it seems reasonable: take $\mathcal{E}_k=\{]0,1/k[\}$ with mass $1$. One would expect the measure $\mu$ to be the Dirac mass at $0$ even though $\bigcap_kE_k=\emptyset$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat For (a), why is $\varnothing\in\mathcal E$? We need this to be able to consider the empty cover. About $E_\infty$, I don't understand your argument. Did you mean $\bigcap_k E_k$ in place of $\bigcap_k \mathcal E_k$? Even then, it's not quite clear why we should take $\overline{E_k}$ instead of $E_k$.

Comment: I'm not saying $\emptyset\in\mathcal{E}$, I'm saying the cover that contains no sets from $\mathcal{E}$ (i.e. the empty cover) covers $\emptyset$. I'm not presenting an argument (I even write "I don't have a good argument for ..." !) I'm saying that it's not too surprising if we consider the example I provide. I do mean the intersection fo the $E_k$ (not the $\mathcal{E}_k$).

Comment: Doesn't the definition strictly require us to choose a cover $\bigcup_{i} U_i$ using $U_i \in \mathcal E$? What do you mean by *"cover that contains no sets from $\mathcal E$"*? I don't think such covers are even allowed.

Comment: The empty cover **does** contain only elements from $\mathcal{E}$ ... Indeed we selected no sets at all.

Comment: Is this some sort of vacuous argument? I'm unable to understand how the empty cover contains elements from $\mathcal E$, unless you allow $\varnothing\in\mathcal E$, which isn't obvious (or even true, I guess). @OlivierBégassat

Comment: I'm considering the cover $(U_i)_{i\in\emptyset}$ i.e. I cover $\emptyset$ with the cover $()$ containing nothing at all. There's no trickery at all.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, the definitions given by the OP have $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} U_{i}$ so it seems the index set is $\mathbb{N}$ by fiat.

Comment: "What is the point of all this? What have we achieved? I need help understanding the bigger picture!"  My guess is the reason Falconer does not want to go into the proof that the construction gives a measure is precisely in order to skip to "the point of all this."

Comment: very cool post OP

Comment: Consider $\mathcal E_n=\{U_n\}$ where $U_n=(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Then $\mu(U_n)=1$ for all $n$. Hence if empty sums or covers are not allowed, we have a problem.

Comment: For question 3, closing $E_k$ guarantees the intersection is non empty. Consider $\mathcal E_n=\{(0,\frac{1}{n})\}$

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Correct me if I'm wrong, but $\mu(U_n) = 2/n$ in your example, right? Anyway, I think empty covers should be allowed.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor The construction has the mass stay constant. So if I only take one subset at each step, then the mass of the subset will be the total original mass hence one. My construction will give the dirac delta measure at zero.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor To answer 6, this process can be used to give a non zero measure to the classical  middle third Cantor Set.